# xampp apache ports changing / scanning

Tags: apache, xampp, port, moodle, port-scanning

I am running xampp on an external facing server (i know people recommend against this, we've configured it pretty tightly [I think!]).  We are using control panel v3.1.0 and it has a column called Port(s).  The apache ports shown keep changing, and cycling through the udp ports, as well as listing the standard apache ports:

```
Port(s)
80, 443

80, 443, 1245

80, 443

80, 443, 1246

80, 443, 1247
```

What does this mean?  Are we getting scanned (I don't control our firewall but they say the ports are locked down to 80 and 443)?

httpd.conf

```
 #Listen 0.0.0.0:80
 #Listen [::]:80
 Listen 80
```

httpd-ssl.conf

```
 #Listen 0.0.0.0:443
 #Listen [::]:443
 Listen 443
```

It might also be worth noting that this machine is running moodle 2.2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These are the ports that MySQL discuss with Apache.
3306 <-> 1245 etc.

Nothing to worry about.